# SharePoint API ClientContextLoad property not initialized

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have the following code (SharePointUpload is a custom class I have that contains a Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File object):

```
private static bool LoadSharePointFile(SharePointUpload fileUpload)
{
    ClientContext clientContext = HttpContextManager.SharepointClientContext;
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileUpload.FullSharepointPath);
    clientContext.Load(file, f => f.CheckOutType, f => f.MajorVersion);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    fileUpload.File = file;
}
```

Immediately after this method returns, I access the CheckOutType property like the following:

```
if (fileUpload.File.CheckOutType != CheckOutType.None)
{
  ...
}
```

And I get this error:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException:
>   The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been
>   requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be
>   explicitly requested.
>        at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject.CheckUninitializedProperty(String
>   propName)

Why am I getting this error? Isn't that property initialized as I've defined it in the context's Load method?

Answer (score 0):

You should load the web context first

```
using (ClientContext ctx = ....))
{
    Web web = ctx.Web;
    ctx.Load(web);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();


    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileUpload.FullSharepointPath);
clientContext.Load(file, f => f.CheckOutType, f => f.MajorVersion);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: I modified my code to load the web object and execute that query before accessing this property and I still get the same error when attempting to access the CheckOutType property